# How do I call the createRecord function inside an aura:if tag?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.recordTypeId == '0121l000000566UAAQ'}" >
<lightning:button label='Button' onclick='{!c.createRecord}'/>
</aura:if>`
```

Currently I am calling button to call my createRecord function, but I want to directly call the function when aura if becomes true. 
Should I write another component and call the component ? is that only solution or can we do in any other way ? any help please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you see you aura:if becomes true when the record type id matches `0121l000000566UAAQ`

This will most likely get set from parent when the component is intantiated or some other event in the aura component, so when the record type id is set in the same function in javascript controller/helper you should call the create record method. there is no need for a separate button for this.

Also you should never hard-code recordtype id like this since it will change from sandbox to sandbox, you should query it dynamically using its developer name.

Answer (score 0):

@user3920709  your use case is not clear, if you want create record on button click you 
 just have to use e.force:createrecord event

cmp

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.recordTypeId == '0121l000000566UAAQ'}" >
<lightning:button label='Button' onclick='{!c.createRecord}'/>
</aura:if>
</aura:component>
```

controller.js

```
 ({
   createRecord: function(cmp,event,helper){
   var createRecordEvent = $A.get('e.force:createRecord');
            if ( createRecordEvent ) {
                //map the new fields here
                createRecordEvent.setParams({
                    'entityApiName': 'Case',
                    'recordTypeId': cmp.get("v.recordtypeid"),
                    'defaultFieldValues': {
                        'status' : 'Testing',
                        'customfield__c' : 'anyvalue' // you can give what ever fields you want to bind
                    }
                });
                createRecordEvent.fire();
 }
})
```